# Python mysql output from function not working

Tags: python, mysql, function, parameters

I'm relatively new at Python but have more experience in Java, so I understand most of the concepts. However, I keep having issues with MySQL and passing information back from a function using MySQL
 to use in another function later.

I need to make complex MySQL queries with multiple return field, So I don't want to be running multiple SQL queries for each SQL field as this will smash the database. 
Saying that the below is a small example of what I'm trying to achieve.

I wanted a function to run an SQL query (def connectory_mysql()) that took parameters from elsewhere, (this part works) then take the output of the SQL query and pass back to the main function to use. 
The main function then needs to use the different column results of the SQL query for different parameters.

I can return the result and assign it to a result1 which appears and looks like a dictionary when printed, but I'm unable to split/use the different keys or data from the result1 = connector_mysql(subSerialNum, ldev, today_date)
If i splituse the keys in the dictionary in the SQL function before returning ie ldev_cap = result['ldev_cap']
I can print the individual elements within the SQL function... However, I cant seem to pass the parameters then back to the main function and split them out??

I must have missed something easy or am not understanding something... any assistance or help would be greatly appreciated...

```
...    
result1 = connector_mysql(subSerialNum, ldev, today_date)

print(result1)  #this works and appears to be a dictionary, but I can split it 
                 ## into its elements like:
ldev_cap = result1['ldev_cap']   ##-> this dosn't work here.....???? if i return it as a dictonary..
                #and i'm unsure how to split them when i pass just the paramaters 
                #back if i split the dictionary in the sql function.

...

def connector_mysql(subSerialNum, ldev, today_date):

    import pymysql.cursors

    db_server = 'localhost'
    db_name = 'CBDB'
    db_pass = 'secure_password'
    db_user = 'user1'

    sql_query = (
        "SELECT ldev_cap, ldev_usdcap FROM Ldevs WHERE sub_serial=%(serial)s "
        "and ldev_id=%(lun)s and data_date=%(todayD)s")

    connection = pymysql.connect(host=db_server,
                                 user=db_user,
                                 password=db_pass,
                                 db=db_name,
                                 cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(sql_query, {'serial': subSerialNum, 'lun': ldev, 'todayD': today_date})
            result = cursor.fetchone()

            while result:
                ldev_cap = result['ldev_cap']   #here the dictionary acts as 
                                        #expected and i can assign a value
                ldev_usdcap = result['ldev_usdcap']

                print(result)
                return ldev_cap, ldev_usdcap   #here i can return 

    finally:
        connection.close()
```

Any help or assistance would be greatly apricated...

Cheers
Graham

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should get familiar with the [Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for writing python code.

Based on your existing code, `result1` return as a tuple that contained the value of `(ldev_cap, ldef_usdcap)` (it is not a directory). You get access to the return result as `result1[0]` which corresponding to the return value of `ldev_cap` or `result1[1]` which corresponding to the return value of `ldev_usdcap`.

Alternatively, since you are returning two data, you can access each return data by using

```
ldev_cap, ldev_usdcap = connector_mysql(subSerialNum, ldev, today_date)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feed back, i understand its not a directory but a dictionary, and yes understand the tuple concept which i've tried but dosn't work.

Comment: Maybe you should rephrase your question, what do you expecting from the result it return? and what exactly 'doesn't work'?